Adult circumcision vs Torah prohibition "Lo Yosif" - not to inflict a wound upon yourself (Deuteronomy 25:3)
I understand that uncircumcised adult men who wish to convert to Judaism must have a circumcision to become Jewish.
My question is, how this is reconciled with the Torah prohibition of "Lo Yosif" - which includes not to inflict a wound upon yourself (Deuteronomy 25:3)? I wonder, especially because I understand that the procedure can be far more complex/ painful for adults than for newborns.

A man getting a brit milah as an adult would be following Avraham Aveinu's example, he and many adults in his household were circumcised as adults

Welcome to Mi Yodea! Others will eventually answer, but off the cuff, does the prohibition apply to someone who isn't (yet) Jewish? Also, assuming that it falls under inflicting a wound, there is a general principle called asei docheh lo taasei, that fulfillment of positive commandment overrides any required inherent negative commandment. For instance, wearing woolen tzitzit on a linen garment, where the strings must be wool. That overrides the wearing of the forbidden mixture of wool and linen.

at the least it would be a Mitzvat Asseh being doche a Lo Ta'asseh

@joshwaxman a classic example of that is milah btzaras

Lo Yosif is a prohibition not to exceed the biblically prescribed number of lashes. That means there are times when it's permitted and even required to inflict pain. The point is not do so without authorization.

The very fact that the context of lo yosif is literally whipping someone, when they are commanded to, proves that it has nothing to do with inflictions caused to fulfill a Mitzvah. IMO this is not even a real question.

You need circumcision to become "Orthodox." You don't need circumcision to become a Reform Jew.

Until a man converts how would he have the obligation for a mitzvah not covered by sheva mitzvos bne noach?

B"H
It's explained that the reason Avraham didn't give himself a bris until he was commanded to, even though he kept every other mitzvah on his own, was because of the prohibition of "one who spills the blood of a person...", which includes causing oneself to bleed.
However once he was commanded by Hashem to circumcise himself, then he can.
An action Mitzvah overrides a negative commandment.
For that reason it's obligatory to have a bris even on shabbos (if it's the 8th day and child is healthy enough).
Technically there's no difference in this issue between a child circumcision and an adult one. It's also prohibited to cause someone else, especially a child, to bleed, but the Mitzvah overrides that.
So too the positive Mitzvah overrides whatever prohibition would be involved.
